# How can I use excel pivot table calculated field to subtract two times?

Tags: excel, pivot, field

I have 3 fields in excel. Start, Finish and Total. Both start and finish time set as min and max but when I use calculated field to subtract both times I get random results.

I have dynamic workbook connected to SQL Server and update all the time. I am trying to find out total number of hours worked by each officer based on start and finish time. So I use Min and Max to find that out but when I try to use subtract I get random results but when I do normal =finish-start I get actual result but I need that in calculated field due to pivot table so everyone can use the report.

Comment: Please let me know if you need excel sheet? Thank you

Comment: I've done many thing with pivot tables, but NEVER EVER succeded with calculated fields in "normal" pivot tables (they don't work with date values, they always show the sum, ... ). So I can only suggest to do that calculation in your database.